# Converting 1d array to 2d array nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a 1-d array (as an output of a mongoDB query)
Sorted based on the field ‘number’'

```
results = [{
  user: u1,
  number: 1,
  msg: m1
}, {
  user: u2,
  number: 2,
  msg: m2
}, {
  user: u3,
  number: 3,
  msg: m3
}, {
  user: u2,
  number: 4,
  msg: m4
}, {
  user: u1,
  number: 5,
  msg: m5
}]
```

I want to convert this array to 2-d array as below. Notice that the nested array is sorted based on the 'number' field

```
newResults = [{
  user: u1,
  msg: [{nmsg: m1, number: 1}, {nmsg: m5, number: 5}]
}, {
  user: u2,
  msg: [{nmsg: m2, number: 2 }, {nmsg: m4, number: 4}]

}, {
  user: u3,
  msg: [{nmsg: m3, number 3}]
}    
}]
```

I can do this by having 2 for loops, however, 2 for loops seems inefficient, since the arrays can grow to very large size.

is there a way, may be using a library or directly from mongoDB to achieve the same results ?

Also, structure of Mongodb is very simple

as

```
{
user
number
msg
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using mongodb [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). You need to sort by number (using [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)), group by user, and generate array of data that share the same group by key (using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$push](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/push/)).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: {number: 1}}, 
  {$group: {
    _id: "$user", 
    msg: {$push: {nmsg: "$msg", number: "$number" }}
  }}
])
```

Got such result for your data:

```
{
    "_id" : "u1",
    "msg" : [
            {
                    "nmsg" : "m1",
                    "number" : 1
            },
            {
                    "nmsg" : "m5",
                    "number" : 5
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "u2",
    "msg" : [
            {
                    "nmsg" : "m2",
                    "number" : 2
            },
            {
                    "nmsg" : "m4",
                    "number" : 4
            }
    ]
}
{ "_id" : "u3", "msg" : [ { "nmsg" : "m3", "number" : 3 } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr, I will try it tonight and let you know. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: This works, I'm also thinking aggregate might be a better solution compared to lodash solution. All the processing and computation will be on the Mongo server and not on the main server as the records can be huge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) to reduce and order your results. I used `_.chain()` in the example below because it makes the code more readable and may add efficiency.

```js
var results = [
  { user: 'u1', number: 1, msg: 'm1' },
  { user: 'u2', number: 2, msg: 'm2' },
  { user: 'u3', number: 3, msg: 'm3' },
  { user: 'u2', number: 4, msg: 'm4' },
  { user: 'u1', number: 5, msg: 'm5' }
];

var reduced = _.chain(results)
  .groupBy('user').toArray().map(function(record) {
    return {
      user : _.chain(record).head().get('user'),
      msg  : _.chain(record).map(function(data) {
          return { nmsg: data.msg, number: data.number };
        }).sortBy('number')
    }
  }).sortBy('user').value();

var types = [
  { name : 'str', pattern : /("(?:\\.|[^"\\])*")/g },
  { name : 'num', pattern : /(\b[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b)/g }
]
document.querySelector('code.javascript').innerHTML = types.reduce(function(code, type) {
  return code.replace(type.pattern, '<span class="' + type.name + '">$1</span>')
}, JSON.stringify(reduced, null, '  '))
```

```css
code.javascript {
  font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre;
}
code.javascript .str { color: #007F00; }
code.javascript .num { color: #7F007F; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.0.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<code class="javascript"></code>
```

Comment: Solution works, but I'm thinking it will be a good idea to use aggregate method below for scalability issues. What do you think ?